# PG::ConnectionBad when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, sinatra

I have a ruby app that I created using sqlite3 and now want to put on heroku so I moved it to postgresql. When I run foreman start it works perfectly. Whenever I run the app in heroku I get this error:

**EDIT:**
I am now getting different errors in my log after I made some changes.

```
2015-05-28T12:09:21.138869+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `ruby app.rb`
2015-05-28T12:09:21.526857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-05-28T12:09:24.240862+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize': could not translate host name "ec2-54-83-25-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com (PG::ConnectionBad)
2015-05-28T12:09:24.240881+00:00 app[web.1]: " to address: Name or service not known
```

EDIT: The error message ends referencing line 8 of my app.rb file.

```
app.rb:8 set :database, {adapter:"postgresql",port:"5432",database:"d9fnf2lrkap7tc",password:"_mH7ffuBYU8Wtqx36gxf80ZqFH",username:"axtoixdkvjyboe"}
```

Database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: d9fnf2lrkap7tc
  username: axtoixdkvjyboe
  password: _mH7ffuBYU8Wtqx36gxf80ZqFH
  host: ec2-54-83-25-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Required your `config/database.yml` to investigate problem.

Comment: do you have pg gem in your gem file?

Comment: Yes I have pg in my Gemfile

Comment: can you please paste your database.yml config?

Comment: can you check if you have this settings in your database.yml as
host: localhost

Comment: No it does not, host is set to what was listed as in my database on the heroku website

Comment: No, my question is not a duplicate, I do not have host: localhost, also my code works locally, and his does not. My error is with heroku.

Comment: i see, my apologies.  can you check the log files and tell me if you see anything like this: "FATAL: lock file "<something>" already exists"

Comment: No, that is not in my logs

Comment: I don't think you need to delete this, you'd be surprised how many times someone will have the same error and something like this helps them. Let's face it, whether it seems something silly or trivial, or something complex and difficult it's still a *problem* that needs a solution. Feel free to answer your own question and eventually give it a tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an extra line break in my project which solved my problem, but in going through I learned that I didnt need a database.yml and I could put that under set: in my app file